# Unwanted subscription on observable service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-services, behaviorsubject

Following the cached service pattern I'm using a `BehaviourSubject` subscribed by using a read-only `Observable` created from it in various components

```
// credential.service.ts
private _credentialList$: BehaviorSubject<Credential[]>
readonly credentialListObv$: Observable<Credential[]>

...
this. credentialListObv$ = this.credentialList$.asObservable()

...
getCredentialList(...): Observable<Credential[]> {
    return this.http.get<Credential[]>(
      ``
      ).pipe(
      tap(credList => {
        ...
        this._credentialList$.next(credList)
      }),
    )
  }
```

So from the component I trigger the `getCredentialList` method to emit the fetched list by the `_credentialList$` subject and so all the subscribers to the `credentialListObv$` should get the value.

The problem is that when I create my component I will get unwanted subscription when I invoke the `getCredentialList` method

```
// credential-list.component.ts

private _credentials$: Observable<Credential[]>

constructor(
    private credentialService: CredentialService,
  ) {
    this._credentials$ = this.credentialService.credentialListObv$.pipe(
      tap(() => {console.log("sub")}),
      ...
    )
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.credentialService.getCredentialList(...).subscribe()
  }

  get credentials$() {
    return this._credentials$
  }

// credential-list.component.html
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let credential of credentials$ | async; let i=index">
        ...
```

The result is that when I access the page `"sub"` will be printed twice. The first subscription happens from the `async` pipe inside the component template but why there is another one if I will never invoke `subscribe` on `this._credentials$` from `credential-list` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use **BehaviourSubject**, the first emition is the initial value of it. Then, later, in **NgAfterViewInit**, you subscribe to `getCredentialList` which pushes a new value to the same **BehaviourSubject**.

Try to log the values, instead of typed string:

`tap((val) => {console.log(val)}),`

The first should be the default one that you used when instantiated subject (`this._credentialList$ = new BehaviorSubject(...`)

Comment: You're right but why am I getting both default value and the fetched one? I'm subscribing to `_credentials$` only once through the component template

Comment: So the subscription is only one and the value emitted are two, am I right?

Comment: Because when `credentials$ | async` subscribes it emits the default value of BehaviourSubject and then when subecription from `ngAfterViewInit` emits it pushed new value to your Subject, so then `credentials$ ` emits again

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're also subscribing to the service method that returns the HTTP observable. So now your component has two active subscriptions to one http call.

HTTP methods in Angular complete after emitting one value, so you can safely subscribe to the observable inside the method.

```
getCredentialList(...): Observable<Credential[]> {
    this.http.get<Credential[]>(
      ``
      ).pipe(
      tap(credList => {
        ...
        this._credentialList$.next(credList)
      }),
    ).subscribe();
  }
```

Then in your component, leave your observable the same, but don't subscribe to the method.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.credentialService.getCredentialList(...);
}
```

Now invoking the service method triggers the HTTP request, and your private `_credentials$` observable still gets the data from the BehaviorSubject.

---

**Edit:** Since you said you don't want to subscribe to anything inside the service, I can offer you a solution that only requires one subscription in the component template.

```
// credential.service.ts
private credentialParams$ = new Subject<ApiParameters>();
public credentialListObv$: Observable<Credential[]>;

...
this.credentialListObv$ = this.credentialParams$
.pipe(
  switchMap(urlParameters=>
    this.http.get<Credential[]>(`url with ${urlParameters}`)
  )
);

...
getCredentialList(newParams:ApiParameters): void {
  this.credentialParams$.next(newParams);
}
```

Use the subject to emit whatever parameters you need for your API call. Then the observable takes that emitted parameter and directly returns the HTTP request observable.

```
// credential-list.component.ts

public credentials$: Observable<Credential[]>

constructor(
    private credentialService: CredentialService,
  ) {
    this.credentials$ = this.credentialService.credentialListObv$.pipe(
      tap(() => {console.log("sub")}),
      ...
    );
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.credentialService.getCredentialList(apiParams);
  }

// credential-list.component.html
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let credential of credentials$ | async; let i=index">
```

In the component, we only subscribe to the service observable. On the init lifecycle, we invoke the service method. This causes your component observable to react to the HTTP request that will be returned from the service observable.

P.S. It is okay to subscribe to something within a service, if you know that observable completes (like HTTP requests).

Comment: I cannot subscribe inside the service

Comment: Updated my answer for you.

Comment: Anyway I'm subscribing once, the subscription to the observable returned by the service method doesn't deal with the tap log

Comment: Your async pipe in the template is also triggering a subscription.

Comment: Yes, but that's the only subscription I'm making to _credentials$ (credentialListObv$)